# Touch pad does not work in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, touchpad, acer

[image: my device information]

[image: input devices]

Touchpad is not working on Acer Aspire E 15 E5-574G.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to add text information instead of pictures? This allows copy-pasting and helps to provide your help.

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible that your Ubuntu doesn't support Touchpad. To be sure, try this command:

```
less /proc/bus/input/devices
```

After that or if you have already done step 3 you can try the following commands:

```
sudo rmmod i2c_hid
sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

If the above command shows you 'touchpad', then you will have to update your GRUB. 
Here's how:

First execute the command:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

and then, 
Replace the command:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash`"

with this below command:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"`

Save your file and exit.

Again, run this command:

```
 sudo update-grub
```

and then restart your laptop. If all goes well, your issue will no longer be in existence. Let us know the update via the comments section.

Comment: thank you for your help.. but I still have this problem... now I'm with usb mouse..

Comment: Oh. I am sorry to hear that. If you have any screenshots to share with us highlighting the current errors, kindly edit your question accordingly.